# Displaying Latest Record and Join Multiple table

Tags: mysql, sql

how do I join multiple tables and displaying each users sold item, display the latest record who sold the items
I need output like this

Sold by: 
"jon" item "#1" "book" with a price of "1000"

tried :

```
SELECT uid , users.name AS uname, transact.transaction_id AS transacted INNER JOIN users on transaction_table.c_id=c_table.c_id


   User table
    --------------------------
    | uid | name |  timezone |
    --------------------------
    |  1  | jon  |  +1 gmt   |
    |  2  | mix  |  +2 gmt   |
    |  3  | vic  |  +1 gmt   |
    --------------------------


    transaction table
    -------------------------------
    | transaction_id | uid | c_id |
    -------------------------------
    | dafsf22sdfssgs | 2   |  1   |
    | 23425asda3afaa | 1   |  1   |
    -------------------------------


    C-table
    ------------------------
    | c_id | c_name | price |
    ------------------------
    |  1   | book   | 1000  |
    |  2   | comic  | 100   |
    |  3   | notes  | 10    |
    -------------------------
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please see: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to group by item name and get the total

```
select u.name,count(*) as count, c.c_name, c.price*count(*) as totalPrice from user u
inner join transaction t on u.uid=t.uid
inner join ctable c on c.c_id=t.c_id
group by c.c_name
```

If you want to query all the transactions

```
select u.name, c.c_name, c.price from user u
inner join transaction t on u.uid=t.uid
inner join ctable c on c.c_id=t.c_id
```

If you just want to return the last transaction info

```
select u.name, c.c_name, c.price from user u
inner join transaction t on u.uid=t.uid
inner join ctable c on c.c_id=t.c_id
order by t.transaction_id desc limit 1
```

And one more thing. It is a much much more better practice if your field names are consistent.